# hibernate avoid duplicates in database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

How to avoid duplicates in the database.

```
'1', 'Male'
'2', 'Male'
'3', 'Female'
```

to only save

```
'1', 'Male'
'2', 'Female'
```

or:

to only save

Countries

```
    '1', 'UK'
    '2', 'Brazil'
    '3', 'China'
```

My database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bi_person` (
        `id_person` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `last_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
         `additional_info` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `gender_id` VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE REFERENCES bi_gender
    ) COLLATE='utf8_bin';
```

---

-- Table 'bi.gender`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bi_gender` (
        `id_gender` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `name`  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL  
    ) COLLATE='utf8_bin';
```

---

-- Table 'bi.country`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bi_country` (
        `id_country` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `name`  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL 
    ) COLLATE='utf8_bin';
```

I have models with relation many to many - person countries and one to many person-->gender

Model:

```
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_book")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="bi_person_country", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_country"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_person"))
    private Set<Person> persons;
```

Model gender:

```
@Table(name = "bi_gender")
@Entity
public class Gender {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

Person entity:

```
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_person")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "additional_info")
    private String additionalInfo;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "persons")
    private Set<Country> countries;
```

Adding person object:

Person person = Person();

```
            Gender gender = new Gender();

            gender.setGenderName(pepPersons.get(a).getGender());

            gender = genderRepository.save(gender);

            Country country = new Country();

            country.setCountryName(pepPersons.get(a).getCountry());

            country = countryRepository.save(country);

            person.setName(pepPersons.get(a).getFirstName());
            person.setLastName(pepPersons.get(a).getLastName());
            person.setAdditionalInfo(pepPersons.get(0).getFunction());
            person.setGender(gender);

            Set<Country> countries = new HashSet();
            countries.add(country);
            person.setCountries(countries);

            personRepository.save(person);
```

Comment: the country and gender tables are master data, containing unique countries and genders respectively, that is why you do not want to add entries to it?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use [`unique index`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/) to prevent a duplicates in DB table.

In MySQL it could be done with statement:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_bi_gender_name
ON bi_gender(name);
```

It would guarantee uniqueness on DB Level.

Regarding Hibernate annotations:

As far as I know Hibernate doesn't make any check for uniqueness.

Based on Hibernate JavaDoc for [`@Column`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#unique())

> This **is a shortcut for the UniqueConstraint annotation** at the table level and is useful for when the unique key constraint corresponds to only a single column. This constraint applies in addition to any constraint entailed by primary key mapping and to constraints specified at the table level.

and `@UniqueConstraint`

> Specifies that a unique constraint is to be included in the generated DDL for a primary or secondary table.

So it is helpful if you are generating DB Schema with Hibernate as well as for documentation purposes.

Comment: @user9381327 on table where you want to have unique column. in my example, you will have unique values in column `name` in table `bi_gender`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to declare that column as unique : `@Column(unique = true)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the country and gender tables are master data, containing unique countries and genders respectively.

In that case you do not need cascade, in application fetch the required gender set it on person and persist person. remove the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

**update**

```
Gender male = genderRepository.findByName("Male");
person.setGender(male);
...
personRepository.save(person)
```

Comment: i deleted cascade = CascadeType.ALL, but nothing changed

Comment: Need to see your code where you create and persist Person.

Comment: I added persist Person

Comment: You do not need to explicitly persist gender and country every time you persist `Person`. Find the required gender from db, set it on `Person` you are about to persist and then persist it.

Comment: how it should looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name = "name",unique = true, nullable=false) 
private String name;
```

use this in entity to avoid the duplicate name

Comment: I added @Column(unique = true) for column name in gender and countries entity., but nothing changed.

Comment: please allow you ORM to create the table, drop and check once. because this constrain will work during ddl time not in rum time

Comment: I droped tables, added @Column(name = "name"), but still '1', 'Male'
'2', 'Male'
'3', 'Male'
'4', 'Male'
'5', 'Male'

Comment: @Column(name = "name",unique = true, nullable=false)   use this and check again

Comment: nothing changed... @Column(name = "name", unique = true,  nullable=false)
    private String name; but still duplicated

Comment: all the tables are created by hibernate not by yourself drop the table and check it should work  or refer this if you have more unique constrains

Comment: try this @Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name"})})  please drop the table and check for all cahnges to reflect

Comment: adding unique constraint will make adding person entity fail incase of duplicate names.

Comment: yes you need to add it for country name and gender name where duplicate need to prevent and not for person name right ? i told this for this use case '1', 'Male'
'2', 'Female' for the 3rd comment you said

Comment: if you want dupliate names for person remove unique in column annotation